# Safe to remove entries in 12.04 sources.list?

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, package-management, update-manager

Recently, every time I have run `sudo apt-get update` with 12.04 Precise there have been two 404's (note: I don't have the rep to post more than 2 links, so I've removed the 'http://' from the URLs below for the sake of the question):

> Err archive.ubuntu.com hardy/universe Sources
>     404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
>     Err archive.ubuntu.com hardy/universe i386 Packages
>     404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

When I run the update manager GUI, it always notified me that my last check was stale by X number of days (at the time of writing, the last check was stale by 57 days.

So I commented out the last two entries in my /etc/apt/sources.list, which are:

> ## For legacy gcc
>      deb archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
>      deb-src archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe

...and the updates run without any problems now (although there wasn't really any noticeable negative effects before-hand, just that the errors were concerning me. The red exclamation in the toolbar and associated error message were concerning me too).

So my question is, am I missing out on something important and should I be replacing those hardy URLs I commented out with something else?

Comment: Not really, newer archives will overrule the old ones...but if I may be so blunt: Why on earth do you have repositories enabled that belong to a more than 4 year old Ubuntu version ?

Comment: I didn't add anything manually. I should have mentioned in the question, this is an upgrade from the last LTS release (lucid), and that was a fresh install. I assumed they were meant to be there since the comment mentions legacy.

Comment: I understand. Don't worry, it is safe to remove them. Especially if you are not a programmer.

Comment: I am a programmer, but I can't remember the last time I used gcc. Will I be missing out on automatic updates for it?

Comment: Heh heh heh....maybe you'll be missing out on automatic downgrades ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely remove or comment out (put a `#` in front of them) the hardy entries. Ubuntu Hardy is over four years old and not supported. So the archive isn't active anymore and thatswhy yu get an 404 error.

Comment: I'll vote you up when I have the rep to do so.