# How to fix problematic Ubuntu ppa configuration?

Tags: 12.04, apt, ppa, imagemagick

When I do `sudo apt-get update`

I get following errors:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages                                                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I suspect this is causing me a lot of issues while adding new ppa's and installing other programs. At the moment I am unable to install rmagick gem, which required other packages which wont install cause it says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickcore-dev : Depends: librsvg2-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please help, or the last resort will be to re-install Ubuntu, which I am sure nobody enjoys.

Uname output >>

```
Linux aditya-Vostro-3446 3.5.0-59-generic #86~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 4 09:52:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Post the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: The content can be found at: https://gist.github.com/whizcreed/010fb3052f0430adf4a3

Comment: I'm confused. You have marked the question with 14.04 (Trusty). Your sources.list says "Precise" and your question "Raring"?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safe to remove entries in 12.04 sources.list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/371114/safe-to-remove-entries-in-12-04-sources-list). The entries in sources.list that have `raring` in them are obsolete because raring is no longer an officially supported release.

Comment: @A.B. I was under the impression that I was on 14.04, some confusion there I suppose. Yet how do I fix these issues.. ?

Comment: Post the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: @A.B. I know this is really dumb of me to think that I was using 14.04 :( The output of the command can be found at: https://gist.github.com/whizcreed/d4aabb71b57ec2dd3a86

Comment: Do you want to continue using Precise?

Comment: @A.B. It does not really matters to me.. I only want my os to work well.. I will eventually reinstall ubuntu today or tomorrow. But for now need to resolve these issues, as I am middle of task at the moment. Also will it break my existing setup of rails etc?

Comment: @karel This isn't a duplicate, read the comments.

Comment: @A.B. Of course, I read the comments before I posted my comment, and your comment notwithstanding I still think its a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your information, the output of `lsb_release -a` is

```
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:cxx-3.0-amd64:cxx-3.0-noarch:cxx-3.1-amd64:cxx-3.1-noarch:cxx-3.2-amd64:cxx-3.2-noarch:cxx-4.0-amd64:cxx-4.0-noarch:desktop-3.1-amd64:desktop-3.1-noarch:desktop-3.2-amd64:desktop-3.2-noarch:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.0-amd64:graphics-3.0-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-3.2-amd64:printing-3.2-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch:qt4-3.1-amd64:qt4-3.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

The error messages are based on *Raring*.

To fix this, run this commands:

```
sudo sed -i 's/raring/precise/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -name "*.list" -print0 | sudo xargs -0 sed -i 's/raring/precise/g'
sudo apt-get update
```

So that the entries are corrected to match your system.

Comment: I am unable to run the second command.. it says.. permission denied.. even while using sudo.. More exactly, it says:sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/apt/sedq1oPsd: Permission denied

Comment: Sorry, corrected

Comment: forget this command. =) run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Sorry my bad.. Now I get less errors.. current errors can be seen at: https://gist.github.com/whizcreed/36052e30b495473f304e

Comment: Run again `sudo sed -i 's/raring/precise/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I could make out that I had to change the file name to include path.. cd to directory did nothing.. stil getting 404

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23141/discussion-between-a-b-and-whizcreed).

Comment: Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: Lots of work! O_o

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main  
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
```

You can add all repositories using this source.

Comment: I removed everything from sources file and just added these, but I get errors copied here: https://gist.github.com/whizcreed/e6746f99ccea859b8204

Comment: Could you show me your sources.list, please?